# How to use Firefox and other non-RFC1929 complaint programs with auth'ed SOCKS5? Local proxy chainer?

Tags: windows, firefox, proxy, socks5

I own a SOCKS5 subscription which requires authentication. I want to use it with FoxyProxy and other programs which do not support auth'ed socks5 (just SOCKS5 with no auth). Note that you cannot enter a password in FF or other common browsers in your SOCKS5 settings.

Therefore, I need some program to put in palce of the `?`:

> FF → [no-auth SOCKS5] → ? → [authed SOCKS5] → authed SOCKS5 server I own → [HTTP/S] → final destination.

What can I use for the `?` program?

---

#### Here is additional information:

1. Any answer involveing SSH is wrong. I will not use an SSH server for
   this. I also need a faster protocol (ever tried transferring big
   files over SSH/SFTP? Dog slow even over Gbit lan.) I know how to
   setup SSH tunneling. It works just fine for some things. Not this.
   Please don't recommend using SSH instead.
2. The solution to my problem only has to work with programs which support SOCKS5 (no auth).
3. Browsers do not support SOCKS5 (with the exception of maxthon.com ).
4. The solution must enable me to use FoxyProxy to decide when to use proxy. Most of my traffic can go non-proxied to the web, but certain sites must go over the proxy, and FoxyProxy must enable me to do this. Programs which "capture" other programs and force them through the proxy are not an option.
5. I expect that the solution will be to run a program locally that accepts unauth'ed SOCKS5 connections.

---

#### Appendix A – Reasons for program rejections:

1. FreeProxy - No remote proxy authentication entry possible
2. Advanced Proxy Manager - Cannot specify credentials
3. ProxyTunnel "GUI" - SSH tunnel only (as with PuTTy Below)
4. HTTPTunnel - Cannot specify remote SOCKS5 proxy and local listen port at the same time
5. PuTTy - SSH tunnel only (yes, it can listen on SOCKS5. That's not enough)
6. Freegate - Cannot specify credentials
7. Sockscap - Not compatible with modern Windows versions
8. Your Freedom - Forces you to use "freedom" server.
9. WideCap - Forces you to capture an entire program image. (You cannot have some sites proxied and others not.)
10. AdvOR - Forces you to use the TOR network.
11. Privoxy - No SOCKS5 forwarding. No password entry ability (c.f., privoxy.org/user-manual/config.html )
12. Firefox itself - I know [mozillaZine](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.automatic-ntlm-auth.allow-proxies) might make you think that FF can prompt you for proxy creds. It cannot.
13. FreeCap - Same problem as with WideCap
14. Proxy Server Agent (as described [here](http://www.hackingtricks.in/2011/01/how-to-create-proxy-chain-proxy.html)) - Program does not accept DNS names for proxy servers. Program reports that my proxy is "bad" and refuses to use it. Program crashes instantly when any traffic hits it.

Comment: Does your proxy subscription provider have any suggestions for client software?  It also might be worth checking to see if they have alternate proxy protocols you can connect with, ie, HTTP Proxy (which supports HTTPS via CONNECT), which Firefox **can** talk to.

Comment: **Proxifier** should do just fine, yet its not free (cost 40$), but the price is well worth it, imho.

Comment: This should be on Super User Puzzle & non Coding Golf SE

Answer (score 0):

For this I would recommend [Proxifier](http://www.proxifier.com).

Proxifier intercepts outbound connections made by Windows applications (I think it also supports Mac) and diverts them through a proxy or chain of proxies.

It will allow you also to choose which applications to intercept.  It supports basic RFC1929 authentication (cleartext) over SOCKS5. It's also in current development and supported.

If you want to go for a secure auth mechanism (GSSAPI) I only know of 1 socksifier that can support that, and that's the OpenText SOCKS client.

Comment: Can you expand your answer to include how the software you are recommending works? Please see [How to recommend software](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers)